# bind failed: Address already in use on a simple code

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ubuntu

hi i'm following this simple tutorial  (from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/udp-server-client-implementation-c/ ) to create a udp client and server  . But i got some issue indeed i always have this error : bind failed: Address already in use

I have already changed the port and granted permission but the error is still there.

Why does this error occur?

Answer (score 2):

After your `socket` call and *before* your `bind` call, you need to set up the socket to *reuse* the address (e.g.):

```
// Configure server socket
int enable = 1;

// This allows you to avoid: 'Bind: Address Already in Use' error
int ret = setsockopt(server_sockd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
    &enable, sizeof(enable));
```

See `man 7 socket` for details.